# How to match or not match several prefixes?

Tags: regex

I have the following data (a [subset](https://gist.github.com/superducktoes/9b742f7b44c71b4a0d19790228ce85d8) of possible [log4j](https://edition.cnn.com/2021/12/15/tech/log4j-vulnerability/index.html) responders if someone is interested):

```
ap://167.172.44.255:1389/LegitimateJavaCla
ap://167.172.44.255:1389/La
ap://167.99.32.139:1389/Basic/ReverseShell/167.99.32.139/99
ldap://x.x.x.x.61k2ev3252274o2ek77941q85t0r9444o.interact.sh/ok6ll9m
ldap://c6ps4rekeidcvgqlsmsgcg37qdoyyknz4.interact.sh/a
ldap://c6ps4rekeidcvgqlsmsgcg37x9ayymcak.interact.sh/a
ldap://c6ps4ipurnhssm2608l0cg37chyyykyhk.interact.sh/a
ldap://c6ps4ipurnhssm2608l0cg37pdyyykbug.interact.sh/a
91fd9fef8958.bingsearchlib.com:39356/
550f7e1deaed.bingsearchlib.com:39356/a
2174d47e8d04.bingsearchlib.com:39356/a
da6d408517b9.bingsearchlib.com:39356/a
5463610592ef.bingsearchlib.com:39356/a
```

I would like to keep the FQDN only (the host and domain) or the IP - so I tried

```
(\S*)?(:\/\/)?(?<interesting>.*)(:)?\/
```

(see https://regex101.com/r/dusRR5/1)

The idea was:

- `(\S*)?` → match or not some letters (`ldap`, ...)
- `(:\/\/)?` → match or not `://`
- `(?<interesting>.*)` → match anything and call it `interesting`
- `(:)?` → ... but stop at `:` if there is one
- `\/` → ... otherwise stop at `/`

The expected result is

```
167.172.44.255
167.99.32.139
x.x.x.x.61k2ev3252274o2ek77941q85t0r9444o.interact.sh
c6ps4rekeidcvgqlsmsgcg37qdoyyknz4.interact.sh
c6ps4rekeidcvgqlsmsgcg37x9ayymcak.interact.sh
(...)
```

But it does not work and my very limited knowledge of regex does not help.

Comment: What should be matched and what shouldn't?

Comment: @Paolo: the FQDN, I updated the question with examples of outputs. EDIT: FQDN or IP

Answer (score 4):

Modified a bit:

`^((?:\S*:\/\/)?\S*?)[:\/]`

The capturing group contains what you are interested in. The key is to use the lazy approach (`*?`) along with the start line anchor (`^`).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3KbQfF/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+:\/\/)?(?<interesting>[^:\/]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aCSPDR/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+:\/\/)?` - an optional occurrence of any one or more letters/digits and then `://`
- `(?<interesting>[^:\/]+)` - Group "interesting": any one or more chars other than `:` and `/`.

Remember that you do not have to escape `/` if you define your regex with a string literal (as in Python, or C#, or using constructor notations in JavaScript/Ruby/etc.).